# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE - Found reserved word

Tags: mysql

I would like to implement an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` solution, as described in the SQL documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

Here is my table

```
|Table|
|Name (unique)|Description|
|Entry1|{empty}|
```

I would like to create a new entry, named Entry1, with description 'test', or, if it exists, update the description of Entry1

Here is my query

```
INSERT INTO Table (NAME, DESCRIPTION) VALUES ('Entry1', 'test') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE DESCRIPTION = 'test';
```

I have read a lot of documentation, and other topics here, but I can't find what I am doing wrong.

The error message is:

*Expecting ";", found reserved word "ON" at line 1*

Comment: Would you be so kind to post the error message you get? What are you not able to do?

Comment: I forgot the error message, indeed. I cannot get to execute the query, because of this error.
Thank you for you help

Answer (score 2):

`NAME` is the reserved MySQL keyword. Put it inside backticks:

```
INSERT INTO Table (`NAME`, DESCRIPTION)
VALUES ('Entry1', 'test') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE DESCRIPTION = 'test';
```

You can go through a comprehensive list of [keywords here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html).

Comment: My bad, I forgot to put on the error message. It seems to be more in the "ON" part.

Comment: @MaximeVisconte Can you provide a sqlfiddle example?